# How to get Precision, Recall, Accuracy and F1 for Binary Class

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-ml

I'm building a machine learning model using Apache Spark's ML library and let's say RandomForestClassifier.

I divide the dataset to training and test as below

```
(tr,test) = dataframe.randomSplit([0.8,0.2]), seed = 23)
```

apply the model

```
rf = RandomForestClassifier(numTrees=10,featuresCol = "features", 
labelCol = "label")

model= rf.fit(tr)

prediction = model.transform(test)

eval = BinaryClassificationEvaluator(rawPredictionCol="rawPrediction")

eval.evaluate(prediction)
```

I'm under the impression that this gives me AUC which is not accuracy. How do I get the Precision, recall, F1 and accuracy for this model?

My class variable is binary (0 or 1).

Comment: the Scala version of the metrics class has recall, precision and f1 https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-evaluation-metrics.html - for some reason the python API doesn't

Comment: Actually it does, you will have to use MulticlassMetrics instead of BinaryClassificationMetrics, just scroll down a little https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-evaluation-metrics.html#label-based-metrics

Answer (score 0):

AUC is the area under the ROC curve. Nothing to do with accuracy, but more useful metric according to my opinion. Gives a much better overview of your model's capability. 
All the metrics you need are here:
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-evaluation-metrics.html#binary-classification
Take notice that all the metrics are computed towards one label (depends if your true positives are the 0s or the 1s). If you have a class imbalance and you compute your metrics for the major class (lets say the 1s), then your results might be misleading. So use the label that is more important for your model to correctly classify. 
Please, read the documentation carefully before using the metrics to fully understand what they are all about.
Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use MulticlassMetrics to get precision and recall.

```
predictionAndLabels = prediction.select("prediction","label").rdd
# Instantiate metrics objects
multi_metrics = MulticlassMetrics(predictionAndLabels)
precision_score = multi_metrics.weightedPrecision
recall_score = multi_metrics.weightedRecall
```

Alternatively, you can get the Confusion Matrix and calculate your own.

```
confusion_matrix = multi_metrics.confusionMatrix().toArray()
```